# Map.computeIfAbsent() mapping function always invoked?

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda

As I read the API documentation, the mapping function is only to be called if the key is not present (absent) in the map, but in the following code from Bloch's Effective Java 3ed p.225 (slightly modified), it appears that the method here relies upon the mapping function lambda to populate the TreeSet for multiple hits on the same key:

```
public class Anagrams {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File dictionary = new File("C:\\tmp\\words.txt");
        int minGroupSize = Integer.parseInt("3");
        Map<String, Set<String>> groups = new HashMap<>();
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(dictionary)) {
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                String word = s.next();
                groups.
                computeIfAbsent
                  (alphabetize(word), (unused) -> new TreeSet<>())
                  .add(word);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (Set<String> group : groups.values())
            if (group.size() >= minGroupSize)
                System.out.println(group.size() + ": " + group);
    }

    private static String alphabetize(String s) {
        char[] a = s.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(a);
        return new String(a);
    }
}
```

What am I missing, please?

Comment: `computeIfAbsent` returns the mapped value (the `TreeSet`) if the key is present.

Comment: That seems to be the case.  What is returned, then, if the key is absent ?  The semantics of the method name computeIfAbsent() would seem to imply the mapping is for the key absent condition, not the key present condition.

Comment: p225 of Effective Java, 3rd edition contains an entirely different piece of code (for item 48 Use caution when making streams parallel). Which item is that code derived from?

Comment: When the key is absent, the function is invoked and an empty `TreeSet` is returned.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel  Item 46.  its p. 225 in my pdf.   sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I just found it in my copy, but there it is item 45 Use streams judiciously (p 204).

Comment: yes Item 45.  sorry about that.

Comment: @Michael - I have difficulty understanding how you understand that, which is also I think the case, from the code presented.

Comment: Why do you think it relies on the mapping being called each time: it isn't. It is only invoked when the key is missing from the map, then it will add and return a new empty tree set. In all other cases, it will return the existing (Tree)Set.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel - then where is the treeMap populated if the mapping function isn't called

Comment: Look at the parentheses. ;)

Comment: From the api doc of `Map.computeIfAbsent`: _"If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless null. "_

Comment: @Michael - oh jesus, there it is :)

Comment: thanks everyone ! i've reformatted to show what it is I missed :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, it seems pretty straightforward to me. What's happening there could be rewritten as follows:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> groups = new HashMap<>();
...
Set<String> wordSet = groups.get(alphabetize(word));
if(wordSet == null) {
    wordSet = new TreeSet<>();
    groups.put(alphabetize(word), wordSet);
}
wordSet.add(word);
```

Basically, if the set is already present in the map (found by `alphabetize(word)` key), then it is returned. otherwise, it is created.

Comment: that doesn't actually answer the question, though.

Comment: How come? The code in my answer is what happens under the hood of `groups.computeIfAbsent(alphabetize(word), (unused) -> new TreeSet<>()).add(word);`. Is something still unclear?

Comment: did you open the code for the method, or are you simply proposing a rewrite ?  I'm asking specifically about the implementation of the API method.

Comment: No, I mean that's exactly how it works. (Almost; I forgot to add the value back). See for yourself: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Map.java#l951

Answer (score 0):

The `computeIfAbsent` method will only invoke the mapping function when there is no current value for the key. When the mapping function is invoked, the returned value will be added to the map.

From the api doc of [`Map.computerIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)):

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is
>   mapped to `null`), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping
>   function and enters it into this map unless `null`.

In your code, it either returns an existing set, or creates a new empty one (and adds it to the map). Then it adds the word to the set returned from `computeIfAbsent`.